# RBAC is not working in yii

Tags: php, yii, rbac

I have a employee table which it contains emp_id,email,password and roles. I have given user and admin as a value for the field roles. I have also created webuser component which it extends CWebUser. This is my webuser code.

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser
{
public function checkAccess($operation, $params=array())
{
    if (empty($this->id)) {
        // Not identified => no rights
        return false;
    }
    $role = $this->getState("roles");
    if ($role === 'admin') {
        return true; // admin role has access to everything
    }
    return ($operation === $role);
}
```

}

This is my UserIdentity code.

```
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity
{
private $_id;

public function authenticate()
{
        $user= Employee::model()->find('LOWER(email)=?',array(strtolower($this->username)));
        if($user===null)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    else if(!$user->validatePassword($this->password))
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
    {
        $this->_id=$user->emp_id;
                    $this->setState('roles',$user->roles);
        $this->username=$user->email;
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
            }
    return $this->errorCode==self::ERROR_NONE;
}
```

}

This is my controller code.

```
public function accessRules()
{
    return array(
        array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
            'actions'=>array('index','view'),
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow authenticated user to perform 'create' and 'update' actions
            'actions'=>array('create'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
        ),
        array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
            'actions'=>array('admin','update','delete'),
            'roles'=>array('admin'),
        ),
        array('deny',  // deny all users
            'users'=>array('*'),
        ),
    );
}
```

It seems everything is fine. But when i try to update then it is not working and i have tried this for a person who have a admin value for the roles. Please correct me if am wrong.

Comment: I think there is a wrong type assessment beetween the roles you're setting in the authenticate method (it makes it seem like you're setting an array of Role models, related to your Employee object which represents the authenticated user), if this is the case, $role = $this->getState("roles"); will fetch you an array of roles, which you should be iterating over, instead of going for a direct comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is in checkAccess - you need to access a model Employee

```
class WebUser extends CWebUser
{
  private $_model = null;
  public function getModel(){
      if (!$this->isGuest && $this->_model === null) {
          $this->_model = Employee::model()->findByPk($this->id);
      }
    return $this->_model;
  }

  public function checkAccess($operation, $params=array()){
    return  $this->model->roles == 'admin';
  }
}
```

If your app will not be compicated this should work. 
But better use PhpAuthManager (or DbVersion) with full RBAC support